# if statement parent page for child pages

Tags: include

im trying to achieve a code to include a file into pages, these pages has a parent page.
so instead of repeating the code of the "if statement" i use this function but doesn't work.
i want any page falls under that parent page includes that test.php file

```
global $post;
if ($post->post_parent == 974) {
include 'test.php';
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress Development community, Wordpressy! Could you be a little more specific? In which file is your function located? Where is the `test.php` file? Where are you attempting to call your function? Do you receive any errors or warnings (is `WP_DEBUG` enabled?). Please read the [ask] section of our [help] for more information regarding what makes a good question.

Answer (score 0):

**If test.php is in your theme directory**, try locate_template('test.php') instead.

**If it is somewhere else**, make sure that you are trying to include it properly via the path needed.

Just doing include 'test.php' most likely makes it think that test.php is in the root directory of the site as /index.php runs the site (e.g. where your wp_config.php file is unless you have a custom set up.)

Most likely you are simply looking in the wrong place for the file to include.

Try:

```
require 'test.php';
```

If the page dies, it is trying to load, but looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

> i want any page falls under that parent page includes that test.php file

Sound like you need the `is_tree()` function. I've used it several times for this type of functionality. First you would declare this function in your [functions.php file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained):

```
function is_tree($pid) { // $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
    global $post; // load details about this page
    if(is_page()&&($post->post_parent==$pid||is_page($pid))) 
           return true;   // we're at the page or at a sub page
    else 
           return false;  // we're elsewhere
};
```

Then, you would use the function wherever you needed that condition to be met, and use the parent page ID as the argument:

```
if (is_tree(974)) {
     include 'test.php';
}
```

You can see this method in detail over at [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/if-page-is-parent-or-child/).

**EDIT:** This is all assuming you are following proper themeing conventions.